# Ajax not return if Controll API's variable doesn't equal Null

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller

The following Ajax code doesn't even trigger my action if the input variable (a) isn't set to Null.

Ajax code:

```
var ab = "Chocolate Smoothies ya know?";

$("#customerSubmit").submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/Booking/lander",
        method: "post",
        data: { a: ab }
    })
});
```

The following my controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public void lander(string a)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(a);
}
```

And when I do not set it to null, the input received is null.

screenshot when the breakpoint is triggered:

[image]

I've used type/method/etc.. Nothing seems to work

Update:

I even tried the following but no use:

[image]

[image]

Comment: it was just problem of your model binding: you sent `{a: ab}` from client-side but you got it bound with `(string a)`. You should define a model class, for example, `Customer` which contains a property `public string a {get;set;}` then change `lander` method to use `Customer` as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the `[FromBody]` attribute in the Endpoint:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/Booking/lander",
    method: "post",
    data: {a: ab}
})
```

`public void lander([FromBody]string a)`

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Tested locally and changed the example, you need to send a json object